# Gradle can't execute an Ant target

Tags: ant, gradle

I have a gradle task that has a dependsOn and then needs to execute an Ant task called runcukes.  Gradle won't call the ant task, however:

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'

task runCukes(dependsOn: restoreSchema) {
    runcukes
}
```

Running gradle with -d shows that gradle doesn't recognize the Ant target runcukes:

```
    Finished executing task ':restoreSchema'
17:28:37.506 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :runCukes
17:28:37.506 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter                                                                    ]                                                                               
Starting to execute task ':runCukes'
    17:28:37.507 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter                                                                     ]                                                                               
    Skipping task ':runCukes' as it has no actions.
    17:28:37.507 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter
```

Gradle doesn't recognize that it has to execute the ant target runcukes.

The gradle docs don't show anything as complicated as a task that has a dependsOn that then executes an ant task.  (They only show "Hello World" examples as dependencies.)

What do I have to do to get Gradle to execute an Ant task after executing a dependsOn?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just putting the Ant task name into the configuration block of a task won't execute it. This should do what you want if I understood your requirements correctly:

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'

runcukes.dependsOn restoreSchema
task runCukes(dependsOn: runcukes)
```

Comment: That works.  Thank you very much.  I wouldn't have figured that out from the Gradle docs.

Comment: @DeanSchulze Yeah, I hear you - same here. Migration from gradle to ant seems like quite the nightmare once it gets more complicated. After taking a closer look at Benjamin's code - arent there braces missing or is that just an alternative syntax?

Comment: @Zainodis Nope, in Groovy - if a method has at least one parameter, parentheses are optional when invoking the method.

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko Thanks for the info :) ! Been doing groovy since a few hours - ugh well not liking it too much, but no way around it, given android studio and all.